# focus() on element triggers keyup event

Tags: javascript, events, focus, accessibility, keyup

Can someone explain to me, why calling the `focus()` method on an element, triggers that elements `keyup` event, when the `focus()` method is called from an `click` event handler, but that handler is triggered by a keypress?

```js
document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.getElementById('modal').focus();
});

document.getElementById('modal').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  alert('Modal element triggered!');
});
```

```html
<div id="modal" tabindex="-1">Some content here</div>
<button id="testButton" type="button">Focus on content</button>
```

[Above is an example, that you can try out yourself.](https://codepen.io/aguyfromdenmark/pen/QWmKJEa) The expexted behaviour for me is, that when clicking or hitting enter on the `#testButton` element, it will simply set focus to the `#modal` element. If you click the `#testButton`, it works, but if you press the Enter key on the `#testButton` as you would do if navigating the page using a keyboard, it does not work as expected. What it actually does, is that, but it also triggers the `keyup` event on the `#modal` element. I have tried to add `.stopPropagation()`, `.preventDefault()`, and `.stopImmidiatePropagation()` to the `click` event handler on `#testButton`, but they dont solve the problem.

Is there something I am missing completely, or is this really how it's supposed to behave?

Comment: `but the behaviour does not seem to be reproducible on there` if you can't reproduce the behaviour, perhaps there's some other code that is causing the issue that you haven't shown

Comment: @JaromandaX Whoops. It actually is reproducible. I will post a codepen.

Comment: You will probably need to either cancel the key press on the button itself or add a delay to the focus with setTimeout so the key press action completes.

Comment: @epascarello Using a timeout before setting the focus work. But I still can't figure out why it's behaving like this, even with the event canceled.

Comment: `It actually is reproducible` - not so far - what browser is this happening in ... certainly not chrumium or mozilla based

Comment: @JaromandaX I can reproduce it in Firefox, Edge and Chrome using the snippit I posted.

Comment: I must be doing it wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX you just focus the button with tab and hit the enter key

Comment: My bad - I thought the keyup event would've been expected since the key just went up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you press space or enter **when focus on a button**, (`keyevent`, `click`) - both event will be triggered.
it just browser default behavior.

details.

1. you **focus** on the button,
2. you **keydown-enter** and this will trigger `click` event.
3. focus to "#modal" before you **keyup-enter**
4. then `keyup` event will triggered when you **keyup-enter**

---

suggest 2 ways.

1. - check whether it is `clickevent` or `keyevent` with `event.detail`

```js
document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.detail != 0) {
    document.getElementById('modal').focus();
  }
});

document.getElementById('modal').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  console.log('Modal element triggered!');
});

document.getElementById('modal').addEventListener('focus', e => {
  console.log('focus!');
});
```

```css
:focus {
    outline: 3px solid #3f3;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal" tabindex="-1">Some content here</div>
<button id="testButton" >Focus on content</button>
```

2. - just prevent event.

```js
document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
});

document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById('testButton').click();  
  }
});

document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.getElementById('modal').focus();
});

document.getElementById('modal').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  console.log('Modal element triggered!');
});

document.getElementById('modal').addEventListener('focus', e => {
  console.log('focus!');
});
```

```css
:focus {
    outline: 3px solid #3f3;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal" tabindex="-1">Some content here</div>
<button id="testButton" >Focus on content</button>
```